# Firebase storage uploads only 130 images at a time from android phones

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload 2680 images(total size 200mb) to firebase storage from my android phone. Using the below code, I am able to upload only 130 images at a time. Is there a limit to upload at a time, or am I doing something wrong?

```
try {              
    for (int i=0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        final File currentFile = fileList[i];
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Product Images/" + currentFile.getName() + "." + MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(currentFile.getPath()))
            .putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(currentFile.getAbsolutePath())))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("UPLOADCOMPLETED", "onSuccess: " + (currentIterator) +taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());
                }
            });
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("UPLOADCOMPLETED");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After executing till 130, it comes out of loop and executes catch();. 
It also generates 2 error in my logcat:

```
W/System.err:at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.schedule(Unknown Source:4)
W/System.err:at com.ubuyquick.customer.UploadingImages.ProductUpload.pushToFirebase(ProductUpload.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you're overflowing a queue in the client.

If that is the case, you need to have your own queue management for starting the uploads. So:

- Start the first few uploads (definitely fewer than 10, likely no more than 2-3)
- Wait for each upload to complete
- When one upload completes, start another upload
- Repeat until you're done with all files

This prevents overloading the client, and may well be faster too, since you're introducing less contention on the connection.

Answer (score 0):

How did you define 
 `fileList`
? The obvious answer is that maybe `fileList == 130`

Also make sure the child references are unique

Comment: final File[] fileList = directory.listFiles(); no its not 30. It runs till 130 and stops.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 130, I changed it now. What do you mean by stop? Does the loop exit, or is an exception thrown?

Comment: It catches the exception.

Comment: And generates two system errors. `W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.schedule(Unknown Source:4)`
`W/System.err:     at com.ubuyquick.customer.UploadingImages.ProductUpload.pushToFirebase(ProductUpload.java:77)`

Comment: I would try to print the currentFile details of nr [131] which cause the error and see if there are maybe any characters which are not allowed.

Comment: I tried running the loop from 129 it again performs 130 uploads and stops.

Comment: You can try and add an onfailure listener and print the exception thrown there. Maybe it will be different from the one thrown now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181084/discussion-between-qqaa-and-darcia14).